# How to set the CC environmental variable during debian cross packing

Tags: gcc, debian, cross-compilation

I'm trying to build a debian package for an ARM64 platform on my AMD64 Ubuntu OS.
I execute the command

```
debuild -us -uc --host-arch arm64
```

but get the warning

```
dpkg-architecture: warning: specified GNU system type aarch64-linux-gnu does not match CC system type x86_64-linux-gnu, try setting a correct CC environment variable
```

and so would like to know how to set the CC environment variable, as the warning advises.
For my target OS I would typically use

```
/opt/l4t-gcc-toolchain-64-bit-32.1/install/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what is missing on the long run, as OP didn't mention any info about it target package and anyway to check solution my side. Happy to hear your feedback about similar case.

The message is about C Compiler (CC) environment variable is not convenient for the requested target architecture. Try `dpkg-cross` which may help you set all ENV variables for you.

`debuild` is a helper that uses `dpkg-buildpackage`

1. Install `dpkg-cross` package

   ```
   sudo apt install dpkg-cross build-essential
   ```
2. Set the cross-compile config variables and helping flags before building

   ```
   set CONFIG_SITE=/etc/dpkg-cross/cross-config.arm64
   set DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck
   ```
3. Try build it again

If it doesn't work, try passing through `debuild` the cross-compile options of `dpkg-buildpackage`. All steps documented in [Debian Wiki: Building with dpkg-buildpackage](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling#Building_with_dpkg-buildpackage).

**Note:**

If you are build you own package, good to read how to make your package Debian cross-compile friendly: [Guidelines for cross-build friendly packages](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossBuildPackagingGuidelines)